# What can cause hadoop to start a second task attempt even though the first attempt is still running?

Tags: hadoop

I'm using Amazon EMR (Hadoop 0.20.205) and noticed that one of my tasks are in a weird state (see below). A second task attempt was launched even though my first attempt was still running. My other tasks are all finished with one task attempt. What could be the cause?

```
   +--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
   |            Task Attempts             | Machine                     | Status  | Progress | Start Time           | Shuffle Finished                    | Sort Finished               | Finish Time | Errors | Task Logs | Counters | Actions | 
   |--------------------------------------+-----------------------------+---------+----------+----------------------+-------------------------------------+-----------------------------+-------------+--------+-----------+----------+---------|
   |                                      |                             |         | 66.69%   |                      |                                     |                             |             |        | Last 4KB  |          |         | 
   | attempt_201209121354_0021_r_000017_0 | /default-rack/xxx...        | RUNNING |          | 13-Sep-2012 13:10:28 | 13-Sep-2012 13:16:48 (6mins, 19sec) | 13-Sep-2012 13:16:58 (9sec) |             |        | Last 8KB  | 0        |         | 
   |                                      |                             |         | +------+ |                      |                                     |                             |             |        | All       |          |         | 
   |                                      |                             |         | +------+ |                      |                                     |                             |             |        |           |          |         |           
   |--------------------------------------+-----------------------------+---------+----------+----------------------+-------------------------------------+-----------------------------+-------------+--------+-----------+----------+---------|
   |                                      |                             |         | 66.69%   |                      |                                     |                             |             |        | Last 4KB  |          |         | 
   | attempt_201209121354_0021_r_000017_1 | /default-rack/xxx...        | RUNNING |          | 13-Sep-2012 13:14:55 | 13-Sep-2012 13:18:58 (4mins, 3sec)  | 13-Sep-2012 13:19:00 (2sec) |             |        | Last 8KB  | 0        |         | 
   |                                      |                             |         | +------+ |                      |                                     |                             |             |        | All       |          |         | 
   |                                      |                             |         | +------+ |                      |                                     |                             |             |        |           |          |         |           
   +--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hadoop uses [speculative execution](http://developer.yahoo.com/hadoop/tutorial/module4.html#tolerence) by default.  It will launch two instances of the same task and once one finishes, it will kill the one that has not finished.  After a task finishes, the web UI usually removes the speculative tasks from the job's web page (at least in 20.2 it does).

Answer (score 1):

First, you have speculative execution turned on (as indicated by Matt, it is on by default).
Now, speculative execution is useful if, for example, your Hadoop servers are not all equal and some are newer/faster than others.

In our older Hadoop clusters I've seen many cases that the second instance finished faster than the original.